# Amazon ec2 domain redirect loop

Tags: domains, domain-forwarding, amazon-ec2

I am trying to set up a domain for my running instance in Amazon ec2 server.  When i go to bracketfanatic.com i get a redirect loop and the site stops.  I believe that everything is set up correctly except for my Record Sets.  Here is a picture of my records.  [image]

Any help would be nice.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CNAME should be www.bracketfanatic.com pointing to bracketfanatic.com. But that may not be the only thing you need to set. DNS does not normally control redirects, however, there may be something we are not aware of that the host is doing. Make this change and see if that does not solve your problem. If not, then we will have to look further.

Comment: I have added a new image.  I am still receiving the same results.

Comment: @SariRahal Okay. Your problem is somewhere else. I am not sure what web server this is, Apache or so on. It may help to include any web setup information you have. If Apache, you can include /etc/apache2/apache2.conf or your site specific configuration file /etc/apache2/sites-available the file should be something like bracketfanatic.com.conf. Otherwise, a screenshot of any control panel would be okay. Also include any .htaccess file you have. I do not know EC2 so we may have to wait for someone who knows more about the platform. I may still be able to help.

Comment: There was an "Redirect permanent / http://www.bracketfanatic.com
" in the apche2/sites-available/000-default.conf file.  After removing that, the site works perfectly.  Thank you

Comment: @SariRahal Great! I am glad you found it. Now for the fun part...